# Fixed Position Breaks JQuery Hover Scroller

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-position

I've been having trouble with malihu's excellent thumbnail scroller plugin (http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller). In my design, the scroller has to be wrapped in an element which has position:fixed.

Unfortunately, when you do this, a dead zone extends from the top of the scroller, as soon as you scroll the body.

I've tried changing the position settings inside the scroller, but that either breaks the scroller's functionality or does nothing at all.

I'm no JQuery wizard, so I haven't tampered much with the script itself, and wouldn't know what to look for to fix it in this instance, but if anyone more knowledgeable than myself could take a look and offer a solution, I'd be extremely grateful.

I've set up a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nk26k/2/

Oh, and for bonus points, another weird bug is that if you move the scroller vertically after it initialises, then extra white space appears inside the scroller, but that's a distant secondary concern to the fixed position problem.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't removing the `height:100%;` from `.further-info` work? http://jsfiddle.net/Nk26k/4/

Comment: Afraid not, at least not in Safari or Firefox.

Comment: Strange. I made that jsfiddle example using firefox. Looked ok to me. Can you provide a screenshot and comments of what you see?

Comment: Well when you scroll to the bottom on the body element, and then use the scroll box, the content just jumps to the bottom of the container and stays there. Scroll the body content back up, and the scrollbox works as normal again.

I'm on Mac if that makes any difference?

Comment: O.o Isn't that peculiar! I'll have a think.

Comment: Well thanks for sticking with it. :)

I've since found a plugin which is a little more bare bones, but has similar functionality without the quirks of the other plugin:

http://valums.com/files/2009/vertical-menu/final.htm